# Regular expressions - \| not works

Tags: php, regex

I have a problem with regular expression. I have this code:

```
<div class="textPremium">Premium Access 25.04.2014 | 20:59<br>Server: ON | Bandwidth: 200MB<br /></div>
```

I want to match:

> "25.04.2014" (date)
>
> "20:59" (time)
>
> "200" (bandwidth)

Here is my [regular expression](http://regexr.com/38osc):

```
 <div class=\"textPremium\">Premium Access (.*) \| (.*)<br>Server: ON | Bandwidth: (.*)MB<br><\/div>
```

I matched the date and time, but I can't match bandwidth. Adding `\` before `|` doesn't work.

Comment: It's because your string reads `Bandwidth: 200MB<br />` and you are matching `Bandwidth: (.*)MB<br>` (**note the `<br>`**).  This is why you shouldn't use regular expressions to match HTML (because HTML isn't a regular language).

Comment: Post your reflex, not just link.

Comment: `<div class=\"textPremium\">Premium Access (.*) \| (.*)<br>Server: ON \| Bandwidth: (.*)MB<br \/><\/div>`

Comment: Simple error. ~10 minutes wasted. Thank you @Sam

Comment: No problem, you actually had tried to solve it, asked a clean question, and got a quick solution.  Exactly what the community is for, welcome to SO and glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [updated expression](http://regex101.com/r/yB4zI1):

```
<div class="textPremium">Premium Access (.*) \| (.*)<br\s*/?>Server: ON \| Bandwidth: (.*)MB<br\s*/?></div>
```

As you can see in my comment, you were trying to match `<br>` when the line break was formatted as `<br />`.  HTML is not a regular language, and you [should not use regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) to attempt to match it.

However, I improved your expression to match both `<br>` and `<br />` by using `<br\s*/?>`.  This will allow 0+ characters of whitespace followed by an optional `/`.  Also note, that I changed the delimiters from `/` to `~` so that we didn't need to escape ever `/`.